# symfony @Security and redirect_url

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, fosuserbundle

Is possible to use

```
    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
```

and define redirect_url for after login redirect

here is security.yml

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                target_path_parameter: redirect_url
```

i cannot use referrer because its ajax request.

so for now i use

```
if(!$user = $this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login', array(
                'redirect_url' => $request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER')
            )));
        }
```

is possible do this in security annotations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a login success handler:

```
form_login:
    success_handler: some.service.id
```

Create a class that implements `\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` and make the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method return a `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse` to whatever URL you want.

This way you can have whatever custom logic of figuring out the target URL you need.

For instance, you can use the `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::isXmlHttpRequest()` method to figure out if it's an Ajax request and act accordingly.